# Looking for a way so users are limited to one choice, otherwise illegalargumentexception

Tags: java

I currently have two bases. When the program is running, the user is introduced to a question, asking whether they want a thick base. If they do, they type yes and if not they type no. Since, when you make a pizza, it only requires one base; users should only have a single base.

So, if the user chooses yes to in this case "thick base" then, when the next question appears, if the user decides to choose yes again, then they should get an illegalexception error message.

However, if the user chose no to the first base, then it should be ok for the user to say yes for the second base.

update

```
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
            thick.setCost(8.75);
            thick.getType();
            l.add(thick.getType());
            c.add((double)thick.getCost());
            totalBreadPrice = totalBreadPrice + thick.getCost();
            }
            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
            }
            else{
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("yes or no required  "); 
            }
```

I've currently got this, and another for thin. If the user chooses thick then he/she should not be allowed to say yes to the next one, since in a pizza you can only have one base. So, I want it to throw an exception for the next one if he says yes to thick.
thankyou

Comment: Some code (real or example) might help people figure out what you're asking. It's currently difficult to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Isn't it better to stop asking questions after the **very first** "yes"?

Comment: What?..........and updated

Comment: Agreed. Why even ask they want fanta if its not going to be an option? Also, its probably better to list all available drinks and ask one question (which one they want)

Comment: it's a pizza. Users are offered two pizza bases. Do they want the first 1? they say yes or no, if they choose yes or no currently they are asked do they want the second one and they can say yes to both. But, this shouldn't be allowed. So, I want to say if they say to base one then they get an exception for base 2 if they say yes also

Comment: I've updated the message, please unlock my thread.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean coke = ask("Do you want Coke?");
boolean fanta = ask("Do you want Fanta?");

if (coke && fanta) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("You shouldn't drink so much, fool");
}
```